# XML parsing to excel for every Tag in python

Tags: python-2.7, xml-parsing

I am looking for help, where I need to parse very complex XML files into excel for every tag & it's value via python, I am using xml.etree.ElementTree module for parsing.Thank you very much.

I am figuring out how to iterate in loop for all the sub child of root and their child till end .like this :

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 
tree = ET.parse('data.xml') root = tree.getroot() 
for child in root: 
   print child.tag, child.attrib

Comment: `if not code: print("Where's your code?")`

Comment: thanks! I am figuring out how to iterate in loop for all the sub child of root and their child till end .like this :                                                           import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
 for child in root:
     print child.tag, child.attrib

Comment: You may want to update your question with what you've tried so far.